# Twitter Streaming API

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I want to use Twitter's Streaming API to collect all of the tweets of users signed onto my website - of course I would have an oauth token and secret for them, but I want to store their tweets as they make them. Is that possible with the Streaming API? If so, can anyone point me to some PHP library that will help me implement such a task? I tried looking in to Phirehose, but I don't understand how to use that library to get the feeds of all the users signed up on my website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [140 Twitter Server](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/).

Adam creates a lot of great helper code around the twitter API, a lot of great articles too.

Comment: How do you use his code for the user streams streaming API? to get users' tweet information?

Comment: All I can say is read the docs. I downloaded the server myself after having trouble with implementing a naked version from the information provided by Twitter. It will certainly help you if you understand how to work with PHP frameworks.

Comment: I'v spend a few days overcoming all the issues that are active for the twitter realtime api and in the end I'v developed my own solution.Here is the project on GitHub with a detailed explanation how to setup the base project https://github.com/tech-387/Tech-387-Twitter-Streaming-Interface